# kafka-node : unable to pause consumer topic wise

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-node

I already have a kafka consumer group running in multiple instances. I have a requirement to pause the consumption of a particular topic whenever I reach a threshold. When I try to pause the kafka consumer group for a topic, the entire group gets paused. As per documentation, we can pause topics on a consumer level. However, when I create a consumer, it is not consuming any message. The options I used for the consumer are:

```
const kafkaClient = new kafka.KafkaClient({
  kafkaHost : this.brokerUrl
})
{
  kafkaHost: this.brokerUrl,
  groupId: "registeredGroupId"
}
const consumer = new kafka.Consumer(
  kafkaClient,
  topics,
  consumerOptions
);
```

Do I also need to initialize a consumer group with the group id? Will the consumer then be activated and pause topic based consumption?
I tried running consumer and consumer group simultaneously but only the consumer group receives the message.
If I don't create a consumer group, then the group shows inactive in kafka consumers list.

Is there a way to have the same consumer group run on 3 instances as it is running currently and add consumers in each of the instance which would pause the message consumption topic wise?